# Мультифайловая форма

Tags: html, form

Есть html форма для отправки контактов (фио, телефон, и т.д). Нужно сделать что бы пользователь мог добавлять в нее произвольное кол-во картинок, через drag&drop. + должны будут отобразиться превью этих картинок. После нажатия кнопки submit все данные вместе отправляются на сервер.
Подскажите готовый плагин или как можно это реализовать.
Пробовал сделать с помощью параметра multiple у поля файла, но я так понял это далеко не все браузеры поддерживают, да и с выводом превью как то не совсем понятно как сделать нормально.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Я бы посоветовал **jQuery-File-Upload** этот плагин:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki

Использую в своих проектах. Довольно неплохая штука. (это не реклама :):):) я действительноим пользуюсь) :)
Один большой минус - плагин написан без локализации. Т.е. русификация интерфейса довольно проблематична - приходится лезть в самый-самый-самый исходник :)

Ну а так, плагин делает все то, что Вы перечислили: и превью, и dragNdrop...